# Как получить ссылку на Toolbar в FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-fragment, android-toolbar

its a stupid question, but how can i reset toolbar title form another class. Not from MainActivity?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Toolbar toolbar;

 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

And i want to change title from TabAdapter.class. How can i do it?When i'm trying to do it i'm getting a nullpointerexception.

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:

                return MainFragment.getInstance();
            case 1:
                main.toolbar.setTitle("hello world");
                return SearchFragment.getInstance();


        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you speak russian? If answer is "no", use [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: ну вообще я и на русском говорю тоже

Comment: @IlyaKulikov, в таком случае надо вопрос на русский перевести, ведь мы - SO на русском)

Comment: А вас не смутило, что это **ru.** stackoverflow.com и тут все на русском?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам надо передать ссылку на активити в адаптер (через конструктор, например).
2. После этого вы можете найти по ID ваш тулбар и изменять его.

Сейчас же вы создаёте экземпляр класса актвити, коий не является действующим активити и вообще нигде не используется и не отображается.